# How can I pass URL query parameters to a jsFiddle?

Tags: jsfiddle

How can I pass URL query parameters to a jsFiddle? I tried http://jsfiddle.net/mKwcF/?id=123 but all I get is http://fiddle.jshell.net/mKwcF/show/

My example js is simple on a given link above:

```
alert(window.location.href);
```

Comment: there are frames going on, I'd guess the window.location.href is the frame. Try window.top or window.top.top or some variation thereof to get out of the frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jsFiddle devs have said [it currently isn't possible](https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/176#issuecomment-1872479852):

> Apart for the original request for this feature we had no other such requests in 12 years, so it's not on the priority list I'm afraid.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, the solution is pretty simple and does not involve any Chrome Plugin.

Just access top.location.search when using the domain name fiddle.jshell.net :

Working example : http://fiddle.jshell.net/techp9/hfpx9zh5/1/show/light/?test=1

Comment: The example is returning a 404: https://i.imgur.com/E9lWXRV.png

Answer (score 4):

All you need is to add **show** at the end of the URL and then add query

e.g:

if your jsFiddle URL is

```
.../ishaiborovoy/Yx9P899/123/
```

then you should refer to:

```
.../ishaiborovoy/Yx9P6/123/show?myFirstParam=1&mySecondParam=2.
```

This works for me.

Comment: For me this does not work anymore (but it did before!). @Ishai Could you double check please?

Comment: This no longer seems to work, but [@myriacl's answer from 5/24/2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30427062/378779) still does.

Answer (score 3):

I was just trying to figure out the same thing and ran across this in [the jsFiddle documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20181006131559/http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#external-resources).

> **Note:** If you want to use a dynamic resource please add a dummy GET variable i.e. `http://example.com/dynamically.php?somevar=somevalue&dummy=.css`. This will trick jsFiddle to recognize it as CSS resource.

Comment: Hi Brian: can you update my fiddle and show how this works when you add a dummy variable - how do I access it? Btw, I found this (https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/176) is still an open issue in jsFiddle.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure if this is going to be of any real help, but of course I always hope for the best. I looked at it a little more last night and was able to make very minor progess. I'm able to get and set the dropdown value. I would expect something similar could be done with the link, maybe putting some javascript in to get some variable and pass that in at the end of the URL. I am still searching though. Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/syhFT/

Answer (score 3):

As of October 2014 it is a little more complicated than it used to be:

```
If your jsfiddle url is:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u7G7n/44

```
use instead (including some url parameters):
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/u7G7n/44/show/light/?lat1=52&lng1=9&lat2=50&lng2=1

AND send the same url (including parameters) as referer. You can use Referer Control as Chrome plugin:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/referer-control/hnkcfpcejkafcihlgbojoidoihckciin

And configure like this:
[image]

Now the second link (including parameters) should work.

EDIT: Plugin RefControl works well for Firefox:  http://www.stardrifter.org/refcontrol/ Configure with "fiddle.jshell.net" as site, then choose "Forge" (substitute with root address).

Comment: can you explain why we need to interfere with the referer? 
how jsfiddle ignores the query parameters from browser's address? 
why does it work as expected when i click on a link vs copy pasting it?

Comment: A referer tells the destination page from where you were coming. When you type a URL this does not work. About jsfiddle ignoring query parameters: I guess they do not want people to pass parameters to fiddles from outside. They probably actively check the referer and only allow parameters if they are coming from "inside".