# Angular - getting GET variable using $location

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, get

I'm tring to get a `GET` var from the url using Angular `$location.search()` but it didn't work.

This is the code:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bar2o6gf/3/)

[and this is the `GET`](http://fiddle.jshell.net/bar2o6gf/3/show/light/?username=7)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('odinvite', function ($scope, $location)
    {
        //$scope.mytry = 5;
        $scope.mytry =$location.search().username;
    }
);
```

What's the problem? There is other way besides?

thanks!

EDIT -
I tried to add manually hash to the url like this - "mydomain.com/foo.php#?username=7" and it worked! 
But I don't to add hash every time and I want the `$location` to grab it automatically.

I also tried to add this -

```
 app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);
```

to solve it but it gave me an error -

```
Error: [$location:nobase] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$location/nobase
    at angular.js:38
    at hf.$get (angular.js:12196)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.js:4523)
    at angular.js:4340
    at d (angular.js:4482)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.js:4514)
    at M.instance (angular.js:9182)
    at D (angular.js:8299)
    at g (angular.js:7731)
    at angular.js:7611
(anonymous) @ angular.js:12520
(anonymous) @ angular.js:9292
$apply @ angular.js:16157
(anonymous) @ angular.js:1679
e @ angular.js:4523
c @ angular.js:1677
yc @ angular.js:1697
Zd @ angular.js:1591
(anonymous) @ angular.js:29013
b @ angular.js:3057
If @ angular.js:3346
d @ angular.js:3334
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example is working with the second link. It will not work with the first link because the fiddle link `https://jsfiddle.net/bar2o6gf/3/` does not contain a `username`

so, I mocked the `url` using,'url' property of `$location`

**`$location.url('http://fiddle.jshell.net/bar2o6gf/3/show/light/?username=7');`**

Here is the code,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="odinvite">
      <div>
        <br />
        <br />

      $location.url() = {{location.url()}}<br />
      $location.search() = {{loc1}}<br />
      keyword valus is  {{mytry}}
  </div>
  {{mytry}}
    </div>
  
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('odinvite', function ($scope, $location)
    {
        //$scope.mytry = 5;
        
        $scope.location = $location;
      $location.url('http://fiddle.jshell.net/bar2o6gf/3/show/light/?username=7');
  $scope.loc1 = $location.search() ;    
    if($location.url().indexOf('username') > -1){    
        $scope.mytry= $location.search().username ;    
               
    }
  
    }
);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[Here is a **DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Aa2XRXvEjIUerW6lyhun?p=preview)

Comment: I tried it on my WAMP server before and it didn't work.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/2BdlQL - this is the code right now... I shrink it for better debugging

Comment: Just `console.log($location.search())` and check what you are getting. also check this https://plnkr.co/edit/Aa2XRXvEjIUerW6lyhun?p=preview

Comment: print "Object {}"

Comment: BTW - I just read somewhere about the hash - and when I do this - http://localhost/odinvite.php#?username=7 - It works!

Comment: yes, @J.Doe, If you are using hashed URL's, you need `#`, but you didnot mention in the `url` in the question, or in the comment. :)

Comment: I'm not using! I just tried it... my url is "localhost/odinvite.php?username=7".

Comment: where did you try, I mean you changed the url to `localhost/odinvite.php#?username=7`. is it solved now?

Comment: yes. http://localhost/odinvite.php#?username=7 works but this is not the url I'm using... I updated the question...

Comment: add. `<base href="/">` in `index.html` __head tag__

Comment: Yeah I saw this already.. didn't work... I kind of gived up... I add this - ng-init="mytry=<?php echo $_GET['username'];?>" to solve it...not the best solution but I have no time to solve it... :(

Comment: aren't you using angular routing?, it will be simple through routing.

Comment: which router you are using?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with JS Fiddle and the way query string properties work with iFrames.  See here: [How to pass GET parameters to jsFiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527958/how-to-pass-get-parameters-to-jsfiddle)

Comment: I tried it on my WAMP server. It didn't work there either